# How to set a java system property during testing phase

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho

sorry for the dumb question, but I'm really new to maven and I cannot find any answer (I tried, I found something, but I did not understand it ;-) )

The problem is the following:

- I'm building my (eclipse) RCP APP using tycho
- My plugins rely on a system property to enable a debug mode (by default it is disabled, and it is enabled by launching the program with "-Ddebug=true" as java argument)
- I have some tests (packaged as fragment, as suggested everywhere)
- I want that the system property is set when my tests run

How can I instruct maven to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <systemProperties>
          <key>value</key>
      </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update the configuration of your test plugin within your Maven pom:

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <configuration>
           <argLine>-Ddebug=true</argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: It does not work... I think that tycho does not use "normal" junit runners, because it needs to run the tests within an OSGi container...

Answer (score 0):

Tycho uses surefire. You need to use the `systemPropertyValues` configuration element of surefire.